# Cython header directive and __future__

Tags: python, python-2.7, cython, integer-division, floor

What is the correct way to utilize Cython header directives AND utilize a future import?  Python 2.7.x

Example:

```
1: from __future__ import division
2: #cython: boundscheck=False
3: #cython: wraparound=False
<strike>4: #cython: cdivision=True</strike>
4: #cython: cdivision=False
```

This ensures that division works as expected (using the future version), but I am unsure whether the directives are being observed.  Swapping line 1 with line 4 causes division to revert to the standard Python 2.x method.

Comment: Aren't `cdivision` and true-division contradictory? One says to divide ints like C ints; the other says to divide ints like Python floats.

Comment: I'd put future imports after cython directives. Future imports can appear after comments, but compiler directives can't appear after code.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks!  I also see what you mean in your first comment.  cdivision=False (default) is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commented by @user2357112 `#cython: cdivision=True` contradicts `from __future__ import division`. This code is illustrative:

```
#cython: wraparound=False
#cython: boundscheck=False
#cython: nonecheck=False
#cython: profile=False
from __future__ import division

def main():
    cdef double i, j
    i = 0
    j = 2
    print 1/j
    print 1/i
    print 1/2
```

raising:

```
    print 1/i
ZeroDivisionError: float division
```

Adding `#cython: cdivision=True` it will give:

```
0.5
inf
0
```

where you can see the `1/2` being processed as a floor division.

In this case I would recommend to apply the float point `1/2.` wherever you want a float division when using Python 2.x...

Swapping the lines as you mentioned:

```
from __future__ import division
#cython: wraparound=False
#cython: boundscheck=False
#cython: nonecheck=False
#cython: profile=False
#cython: cdivision=True
```

will cancel all [the Cython global directives](http://docs.cython.org/src/reference/compilation.html#globally), because they "must appear before any code (but can appear after other comments or whitespace)".